# Getting list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

Write a function named "jsonFilter" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an array of objects where each object has keys "mass", "density", "temperature", and "velocity" and each key maps to a floating point number. This function should return the input as a JSON string in the same format but with only the objects with velocity greater than 38.11.

```
import json
def jsonFilter(JSON):
    load = json.loads(JSON)
    for key, value in load["velocity"]:
        if value > 38.11:
            return load['velocity'][key]
```

I am getting list indices must be integers or slices, not str. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the JSON look like?

Comment: `load` is already a dictionary it seems. `load["velocity"]` is a value where "velocity" is the key. Share how JSON looks like for more concrete answers

Comment: I am getting error on input ['[{"density": 957.29, "mass": 46.42, "temperature": 73.39, "velocity": 97.98}, {"density": 167.29, "mass": 74.63, "temperature": 26.29, "velocity": 39.96}.

Comment: @Anonymous What's as desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, do:

```
import json
def jsonFilter(JSON):
    load = json.loads(JSON)
    return json.dumps([i for i in load if i['velocity']>38.11])
```

Now:

```
print(jsonFilter(your_json))
```

Is:

```
"[{'density': 957.29, 'mass': 46.42, 'temperature': 73.39, 'velocity': 97.98}, {'density': 167.29, 'mass': 74.63, 'temperature': 26.29, 'velocity': 39.96}]"
```

Comment: Output should be all objects with velocity greater than 38.11, not a integer value.

Comment: @Anonymous Now?

Comment: @Anonymous Then what's desired output in this case?

Comment: @Anonymous But what's the logic behind that?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't the ordering; it was just that you didn't convert your code to a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual input this is a little difficult, but the likely issue is that as you say, you're taking in a JSON array and trying to access it by key. Namely, if the JSON parameter is a json array of json objects, it will be loaded in as a list of dictionaries. Lists can only be accessed via integers. In that case, in order to be able to access the "velocity" of any given object, you first need to index into that object using an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json 
def jsonFilter(JSON): 
    load = json.loads(JSON) 
    array = []
    for i in load:  
        if i['velocity'] > 38.11: 
            array.append(i)
    return json.dumps(array)
```